# Integrating Gmail into rails project for CRM type functionality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, gmail

I'm looking to integrate Gmail into my rails project. The gmail will basically let the user authenticate with their gmail account so they can view, create, and reply to emails from their gmail account.

Is there any major gems that makes this easier than going through the gmail documentation from [google](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/ruby) ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about gem because I am not from ruby background. But I can help you with the way to proceed further with gmail authentication. Gmail provided the OAuth integration which will basically authenticate your app's user on behalf of you.

useful link: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/about-auth

once you get this concept then you can move ahead with more specific question like ruby gem/sdk to integrate gmail OAuth with your application.

Thanks, hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

Going through the documentation is always a good idea even if you can handle it all with gem, understanding what you are doing is helpful and it makes fixing any bugs far easier.

However to answer your question [OmniAuth Google OAuth2](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2) should cover your needs, you will also need to read some documentation though.